# [PHP]Google Speech API enableWordTimeOffsets = true but word in specifict time still not show

Tags: php, json, api, curl, google-api

Someone know whats wrong with my code, i follow instruction to make this API request [Here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics) and here [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig), everything is fine after i need more detailed result, catch time each word. i set `"enableWordTimeOffsets": boolean,`
but results not change.

Here Result :

```
"{ "results": [ { "alternatives": [ { "transcript": "sadarlah kalau dunia ini sebentar dan akhirat target hidupmu Jadi kita kalau ada apa-apa kekurangan teman-teman sekalian Dunia Sementara Akhirat kita akan jadikan target kalau di akhir dalam sebuah hadis yang akan masuk kalau orang mukmin sudah masuk dalam surga lagi capek tidak lagi berlari lagi mulu udah gak ada lagi buang air besar nggak ada lagi buang air kecil semua makanan dan minuman yang tidak dibutuhkan oleh tubuh menjadi energi yang tidak dibutuhkan kau di dunia keluar dalam bentuk kotoran maka akan keluar dalam bentuk keringat yang lebih wangi dari bau kasturi semua laki-laki akan seperti poster ayahnya Adam 60 suku ke langit ini 27 setengah meter dari bab apa yang pendek gak usah khawatir semua perempuan akan kembali ke", "confidence": 0.9507536 } ] } ] } "
```

Here My Request JSON :

```
$stturl = "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:syncrecognize?key=AIzaSyBJRLYrhBnB9fY69ZYDe17eYa8dzKTgKsQ";
$upload = file_get_contents(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'foo.raw');
$upload = base64_encode($upload);
$jsonData ='{
            "config": {
                "encoding": "LINEAR16",
                "sampleRate": 16000,
                "languageCode": "id-ID",
                "enableWordTimeOffsets": true
            },
            "audio": {
                "content": "'.$upload.'"
            }
            }';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $stturl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);exit;
```

Can you help me if know, in my perception the `"enableWordTimeOffsets": boolean,` config is deprecated like this one `"sampleRateHertz": number,` causing the error.

Comment: This is already available in a newer release of `google-proto-files` than `@google-cloud/speech depends on`. So, easy fix: **update the dependency** and bump `@google-cloud/speech`. The only thing is, the option will still be missing from the docs.
**Update Speech module** on` npm` with the latest `google-proto-files`

Comment: thank's for your answer, and yes use `@google-cloud/speech ` is best practice